# best way to show some text in textbox in Window application

Tags: c#, indentation, windows

i need to write a list of url in a textbox in a window apps 
but when i write it he was mixed like http://google.comhttp://google.comhttp://google.comi

but i want to show clearly i already used 
 "\n\r" method but he not worked are any sollution for it

Comment: What do you mean? Do you want to show the some url in 1 textbox like a list?

Comment: yes you are right djerry

Comment: why not use a listbox instead?

Comment: Adding a `Environment.NewLine` is the way to go.

Comment: Shouldn't it be \r\n instead of \n\r? Even better: use Environment.Newline. And your textbox IS in multiline mode, isn't it?

Comment: @ Hans Kesting your tricks good it's work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes  First you need to set the `multiline` property to `True` and better to use [`Environment.NewLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline.aspx) to set the new line.

Or in [stringBuilber.AppedLine("")](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.appendline.aspx)

Hope this will helpo you :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use "\n\r" for line break.

Comment: try also set property of TextBox Multiline = "true"

Comment: replace your html <br /> with the control sequence "\n\r" as anton suggests.

Answer (score 0):

You need set the multiline property of your `Textbox` to true. Then use Environment.NewLine to do a cr/lf (this is equivalent to /r/n)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use a multiline textbox for this. Place Environment.NewLine after each url and it should work.

BTW why are you not using ListBox or ListView?

Answer (score 0):

When working with string or such, try using StringBuilder, it works in my app.

```
private void FillTextBox()
    {
        StringBuilder st = new StringBuilder();
        st.AppendLine("http://www.google.be");
        st.AppendLine("http://www.google.be");
        st.AppendLine("http://www.google.be");
        st.AppendLine("http://www.google.be");
        st.AppendLine("http://www.google.be");
        st.AppendLine("http://www.google.be");
        st.AppendLine("http://www.google.be");
        textBox1.Text = st.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: Not the cleanest way, should have put in a for-loop :)

Comment: i can't use it because i write it using looping when  i try it i see a last link only in a text box

Comment: then try textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + st.ToString();